# html not implementing JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have 3 files FormValidation.html, FormValidation.js, style.css
In the html head I have

```html
    <script src="FormValidation.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
```

which I found and was expecting to "point" the other two (JS/CSS) to the html.

What happens, so when I run it the Form comes up I can type nothing and it doesn't prompt the alerts in the JS, or the alignments from the CSS. I'm not sure what I've done incorrectly as the debug runs with no errors.

As always any tips or suggestions is always appreciated.

Full code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
<head>
    <title>
        Registration Form
    </title>
    <script src="FormValidation.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center";>
        REGISTRATION FORM
    </h1>


    <form name="RegForm" onsubmit="return ValidForm()"
        method=""post>
    <p>
        Name:
            <input type="text" size="65" name="Name: "/>
    </p>
    <br />
    <p>
        Address:
        <input type="text" size="65" name="Address: "/>
    </p>
    <br />
    <p>
        Email:
        <input type="text" size="65" name="Email: "/>
    </p>
    <br />
    <p>
        Password:
        <input type="text" size="65" name="Password: "/>
    </p>
    <br />
    <p>
        Telephone:
        <input type="text" size="65" name="Telephone: "/>
    </p>
    <br />

    <p>
        SELECT YOUR COURSE
        <select type="text" value="" nam="Subject">
            <option>BTECH</option>
            <option>BBA</option>
            <option>BCA</option>
            <option>B.com</option>
            <option>GEEKFORGEEKS</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        Comments:
        <textarea cols="55" name="Comment: "> </textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="send" name ="Submit"/>
        <input type="reset" value="reset" name="Reset"/>
    </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function ValidForm(){
    var name =
        document.forms.RegForm.Name.Value;
    var email =
        document.forms.RegForm.EMail.value;
    var phone =
        document.forms.RegForm.Telephone.value;
    var subject = 
        document.forms.RegForm.Subject.Value;
    var password =
        document.forms.RegForm.Password.value;
    var address = 
        document.forms.RegForm.Address.value;
    /*Javascript reGex(regular expression= check to find sequence 
    of characters that match pattern in text.) for email validation.

    /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/g 
    .The // at the begining and end indicate the regex
    .The ^$ indicate the entire input string should match the regex
    */
    var regEmail= /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/g;
    /*javascript reGex for phone number validation.
    \d{10} means that it should have 10 characters 
    matching any decimal digit including 0-9. */
    var regPhone=/^\d{10}$/;
    /*javascript reGex for name validation.
    /\d+$/g is a global search for non-digit characters*/
    var regName= /\d+$/g;

    //focus() method is the element that will receive keyboard and similar events by default.
    if (name == "" || regName.text(name)){
        window.alert("Please use A-Z or a-z");
        name.focus()
        return false;
    }
    if (address ==""){
        window.alert("Please enter your address.");
        address.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (email==""){
        window.alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address.");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (password==""){
        window.alert("Please enter your passowrd.");
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
//setting password REQUIREMENTS.
    if (password.length <8){
        alert("ALERT: Password should be atleast 8 characters long.");
        console.log("CONSOLE LOG Error: Password must be atleast 8 Characters.")
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }else if(password.search([/[a-z]/])<0){
        alert("Alert: Password must contain atleast one lowercase letter.")
        console.log("Console Log Error: Password must contain atleast one lowercase letter.")
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }else if(password.search([/[A-Z]/])<0){
        alert("Alert: Password must contain atleast one uppercase letter.")
        console.log("Console Log Error: Password must contain atleast one uppercase letter.")
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }else if(password.search([/[0-9]/])<0){
        alert("Alert: Password must contain at least one number.")
        console.log("Console Log Error: Password must contain atleast one number.")
        password.focus();
        return false;
/*
\w =any word character(regardless of case)
^$ =a match must start at beginning of a string and end at the end of the string
[] =character class- match any character contained in the character class.
*/
    }else if(password.search(/^(.*\w){3.*}$/)){
        alert("Alert: Password must contain atlest 3 of the folloing: Uppercase, Lowercase, Numbers, Symbols. ")
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
    
    else{
        console.log("Console log: Success!")
        password.focus();
    }

    if (phone ==""|| !regPhone.test(phone)){
        alert("Please enter valid phone number.");
    }
    if (subject.selectedIndex == -1){
        alert("Please select the Course.")
        subject.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```css
div{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: 100px solid black;
    float: left;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
form{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Edit** screen image of the content.js error mentioned in discussion. **Edit
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbvO0.png

Comment: If you don't see an error message in the console, the JavaScript code is not evaluated or this is not your actual code. The JavaScript code contains a return statement on top level. This causes the error `SyntaxError: return not in function`: https://jsfiddle.net/efus2dzm/. Do you see problems in the network monitor?

Comment: Everything after `}{` seems to be a second copy of the function body, but without a function definition statement before it. Looks like some broken cutting and pasting.

Comment: @Barmar the source is from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/form-validation-using-html-javascript/  I added a few lines for the reGex  being that it was a new concept seemed like a great time to play with what I'm sure can be improved on. but more so just wanted to clarify it wasn't cut/paste took me a while to read through as I was attempting to learn most of what I was doing to eventually apply without needing to follow along.

Comment: The code on the website is wrong.

Comment: If you click on "Click here to check the live code output", the doubled body doesn't appear in that code.

Comment: @Barmar I mean I can certainly remove the doubled, I can even try running it with everything built in opposed to having the js/css in separate files.

Comment: Can you narrow down the problem? If you're having problems with the regexp code you added, just create a [mre] that shows the problem you're having with it.

Comment: @Barmar the problem from what I can tell is that the js/css aren't properly connected to the html.  I type something in the name skip everything else when I hit submit it should have an alert that says to fill out the next box

Comment: `<script src="FormValidation.js"></script>` should connect the JS to the HTML. Are you getting an error in the console when it tries to load this script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256548/discussion-between-navi-and-barmar).

Comment: @Barmar thats what I thought, but none of the functionality of the js is working. when I hit submit it should have an alert that states (123 is not a name, must use 10 digits, ect ) it just "reloads" the page and removes the information typed in.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that would happen if the URL to the JS/CSS is wrong, or it gets an error when it's trying to load them. Either of these should show up as errors in the console. Do you see the script when you go to the Sources tab of DevTools?

Comment: @Barmar okay so when I run it, inspect and go to source tab the FormValidation.js  shows the code(same for the html/css).  all the console says is "live reload enabled."

Comment: Then I don't know why it's not running. If you put `console.log("ValidForm called")` at the beginning of the function, you don't see it in the console when you click?

Comment: @Barmar okay so when I click "send button" while the console log up something pops up but vanishes so I dont get to read it. I'm also seeing where it says  "A form field element should have an id or name attribute"

Comment: Form submits refresh the screen by default. I think you need to pass the submit event into `ValidForm()` and then call `event.preventDefault()` to stop it from refreshing and allow it to run the function.

Comment: @Barmar from what I can tell from copy/pasting the source code in sections (while all in html not 3 separate files" html/js/css") it runs the password changes but line 1 js (function validForm() . . . ) to the (var regName=/^\d+$/g;) seem to be where the error is.

Comment: I don't see a problem with that line. But there's a typo here: `regName.text(name)`. `text` should be `test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick shot out to all who assisted with getting this to work; your patience and understanding is appreciated.

Okay, so below I've attached the final code(s) for HTML,JS, CSS.

HTML- several typos, as far as I could tell the placement of the srs linking the js/css to the html didn't make a difference but I left it at the end of the body tag.

JS - I was trying to access the password variable outside the ValidForm function. I fixed it by moving the password-related code inside the ValidForm function. There was also an issue with the password requirements. This was caused by the regEx in the password validation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Registration Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">REGISTRATION FORM</h1>

    <form name="RegForm" onsubmit="return ValidForm()" method="post" action="your-endpoint">
        <p>
            Name: <input type="text" size="65" name="Name"/>
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
            Address: <input type="text" size="65" name="Address"/>
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
            Email: <input type="text" size="65" name="Email"/>
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
            Password: <input type="text" size="65" name="Password"/>
        </p>
        <br />
        <p>
            Telephone: <input type="text" size="65" name="Telephone"/>
        </p>
        <br />

        <p>
            SELECT YOUR COURSE
            <select type="text" value="" name="Topic">
                <option>BTECH</option>
                <option>BBA</option>
                <option>BCA</option>
                <option>B.com</option>
                <option>ValidForm</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            Comments: <textarea cols="55" name="Comment: "></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="send" name="Submit"/>
            <input type="reset" value="reset" name="Reset"/>
        </p>
    </form>

    <script src="FormValidation.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function ValidForm() {
    var name = document.forms.RegForm.Name.value;
    var email = document.forms.RegForm.Email.value;
    var phone = document.forms.RegForm.Telephone.value;
    var topic = document.forms.RegForm.Topic.value;
    var password = document.forms.RegForm.Password.value;
    var address = document.forms.RegForm.Address.value;

    // Regular expressions for validation
    var regEmail = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/g;
    var regPhone = /^\d{10}$/;
    var regName = /\d+/g;

    // Validation for Name
    if (name == "" || regName.test(name)) {
        window.alert("Please use A-Z or a-z for the Name.");
        document.forms.RegForm.Name.focus();
        return false;
    }

    // Validation for Address
    if (address == "") {
        window.alert("Please enter your address.");
        document.forms.RegForm.Address.focus();
        return false;
    }

    // Validation for Email
    if (email == "" || !regEmail.test(email)) {
        window.alert("Please enter a valid e-mail address.");
        document.forms.RegForm.Email.focus();
        return false;
    }

// Validation for Password
if (password == "" || password.length < 8 || !/[a-z]/.test(password) || !/[A-Z]/.test(password) || !/\d/.test(password) || !/(.*\w){3,}/.test(password)) {
    window.alert("Password must be at least 8 characters long and include at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, and one number.");
    document.forms.RegForm.Password.focus();
    return false;
}

    // Validation for Phone
    if (phone == "" || !regPhone.test(phone)) {
        window.alert("Please enter a valid phone number.");
        document.forms.RegForm.Telephone.focus();
        return false;
    }

    // Validation for Topic (Course)
    if (topic === "") {
        window.alert("Please select the Course.");
        document.forms.RegForm.Topic.focus();
        return false;
    }

    // Setting password requirements
    if (password == "" || password.length < 8 || !/[a-z]/.test(password) || !/[A-Z]/.test(password) || !/\d/.test(password) || (password.match(/[a-z]/g) || []).length +
        (password.match(/[A-Z]/g) || []).length +
        (password.match(/\d/g) || []).length +
        (password.match(/\W/g) || []).length < 3) {
        alert("Password must be at least 8 characters long and include at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, and one number.");
        document.forms.RegForm.Password.focus();
        return false;

    } else if ((password.match(/[a-z]/g) || []).length +
               (password.match(/[A-Z]/g) || []).length +
               (password.match(/\d/g) || []).length +
               (password.match(/\W/g) || []).length < 3) {
        alert("Alert: Password must contain at least 3 of the following: Uppercase, Lowercase, Numbers, Symbols.");
        document.forms.RegForm.Password.focus();
        return false;
    }

    // Rest of your code...

    if (phone === "" || !regPhone.test(phone)) {
        alert("Please enter valid phone number.");
        return false;
    }

    if (topic.selectedIndex == -1) {
        alert("Please select the Course.")
        topic.focus();
        return false;
    }

    console.log("Console log: Success!");
    return true;
}
```

```css
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: 100px solid black;
    float: left;
    text-align: center; /* Center the content horizontally */
}

form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have not closed the `<html>` opening tag properly.
Instead of

```
<html lang="en"
```

Use:

```
<html lang="en">
```

Although in most cases, html runs the code properly even with syntax errors.
The screenshot that you have provided does not have the JavaScript and CSS files linked in the "`<head>`" section.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I'm looking at the html in on my laptop and I do have the closing for the html. I very well could have missed that in the original posting. I do believe I have found the issue, I'm about to start testing to make sure and will update shortly.